# What does 'shall' mean?

Tags: modal-verbs, passive-voice

> Lee said, “St. Paul says to the Hebrews that Abel had faith.”
>  
>   (Mr.Hamilton) “There’s no reference to it in Genesis,” Samuel said.
>   “No faith or lack of faith. Only a hint of Cain’s temper.”
>   Lee
>   asked, “How does Mrs. Hamilton feel about the paradoxes of the
>   Bible?”
>   “Why, she does not feel anything because she does not
>   admit they are there.”
>   “But-“
>   “Hush, man. Ask her. And
>   you’ll come out of it older but not less confused.”
>   Adam said,
>   “You two have studied this. I only got it through my skin and not much
>   of it stuck. Then Cain was driven out for murder?”
>   “That’s
>   right-for murder.”
>   “And God branded him?”
>   “Did you listen?
>   Cain bore the mark not to destroy him but to save him. And **there’s a
>   curse called down on any man who shall kill him**. It was a preserving
>   mark.”
>   Adam said, “I can’t get over a feeling that Cain got the
>   dirty end of the stick.”
>   (Samuel, East of Eden)

The sentence has passive voice and modality at the same time, I’m very confused. Would you improve my understanding about the sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Present-tense *shall* is rapidly disappearing from English; a hundred years ago the *OED* was already saying of the use of *shall* in “hypothetical, relative, and temporal clauses denoting a future contingency”—that is, just such contexts as your example—that

> Where no ambiguity results […] the present tense is commonly used for the future, and the perfect for the future-perfect; the use of *shall*, when not required for clearness, is apt to sound pedantic.

So there is no particular “modality” involved here. The sentence may be rewritten

> And there’s a curse called down on any man who kills him.

That is, any man who kills Cain will be cursed.

What *shall* marks is not modality but register. The speakers are discussing the Bible—specifically, the ‘King James Bible’, a translation prepared when *shall* was in more frequent use, especially in legal contexts.  The Bible’s use of *shall* is reflected in today’s popular catchphrase *shalts and shalt nots* for any set of rules:

> **Vatican issues driving shalts and shalt nots** / The Vatican on Tuesday issued a “Ten Commandments” for motorists … — *Denver Post*, 2007
>    **’Thou Shalts’ and ‘Thou Shalt Nots’ of Strawberry Planting** — *ancientgardenerblog.blogspot.com*

And in fact the Law, which is very conservative, still uses that sort of language:

> Any man who **shall** in this state desert his wife and children, or either of them, or his wife where there are no children or child [...] **shall** be guilty of a felony of the third degree ... —*Florida Statutes*, 2012

So in the Biblical crime-and-punishment context it is very natural for the speaker to fall into this sort of archaic language.